# How to configure authentication from Azure data factory to Google Sheets

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, azure-data-factory

I am trying to fetch data from Google Sheets via the Azure Data Factory.  I have a data flow configured, and a Google Sheets Linked Service configured as well.  The Google Sheets Linked Service is using an API key that has no Application Restrictions, and for API restrictions, it is restricted to Google Sheets. When I test the connection, it is successful.  However, when I try to fetch a spreadsheet using the data flow in debug mode, I get the error:

```
    at Source 'GoogleSheetsOutput': Failure to read most recent page request: DF-REST_001 - Error response from server: Some({
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "The caller does not have permission",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
}), Status code: 403. Please check your request url and body. (url:https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/<my_spreadsheet_id>/values/Sheet1!A2:B3,request body: None, request method: GET)
```

I made a service account, and shared the google sheet with the service account e-mail, and I also shared it with the admin on the account, which is where the API Key was made.

Any ideas what I need to do here?  I would also prefer to use oauth / service account instead if possible, so I am happy to go down that route if there is some documentation I can follow.

Answer (score 0):

> "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The caller does not have permission", "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" }

I tried to repro this and got the same error.

[image]

- To solve this, I changed access of my google sheets from restricted to **Anyone with the link**
  [image]
- It worked and data is previewed without error.
  [image]

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way without making this data publicly accessible?

Comment: As of now, We have only API token based authentication. Refer this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-google-sheets?tabs=data-factory#linked-service-properties).

Comment: but if you are making the spreadsheet publicly accessible with the link, how does the API token help?

Comment: When the API key is used, the Spreadsheet is required to be publicly shared.